# How to implement rank of a field in database?

Tags: database

Trying to find out the best way for implementing rank of a field

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What do you mean by "rank of a field"? And which database?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

Your can try with DENSE_RANK function
SQL Server: 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx'
Oracle: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/dense_rank.php

mysql:

```
set @sno:=0;
set @names:='';
select @sno:=case when @names=names then @sno else @sno+1 end as sno,@names:=names as names from test
order by names;
```